# How can i send for 1 minute via a pipe, random numbers of 2 or 3 figures from the parent process to the child one?

Tags: linux, pipe, c

Additionally to this task I have to count in the child process all the numbers received from the parent process and print them!

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
while [[ $i -lt 60 ]]; do
    i=$((i+1))
    echo $(($RANDOM%9999/10)) | some_other_process
done
```